# static page route using backbone and rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, backbone.js, devise

Im using devise for authentication in my backbone/rails app that uses normal devise authentication which redirects to the root page once logged in. When a user wants to edit their info they are redirected to a static users/edit page. When the page is rendered all the root page info is also rendered along with the edit form, so my question is how do i get backbone to play nice with static routes so the backbone doesn't try to render the root on every static page? do i have to use pushState?

Also another problem is when i navigate away from the users/edit page the hashbangs are just appended to the users/edit url.

Let me know if you need any code in specific, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the root page to stop rendering on the edit page I the code below in the application layout file since all my backbone is being rendered into the container.

```
    <% if params[:action] == "root" && params[:controller] == "static_pages" %>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <div class="container" id="main-container">
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

As far as the hashbang problem it was as trivial as changing the href in the header from href='#/messages' to href='/#/messages'. Just added a /